# How to group a DataFrame using labels and sum them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df=

       c1   c2   c3   c4   c5
d1      5    2    5    6    7
d2      5    6    7    8    2
d3      4    3    1    9    2
d4      1    2    3    7    0
d5      0    3    3    4    5


labels = [0,1,1,0,2] (labels are randomly generated string in range(0,2) )
```

where the 1st element (0) of the labels refer to the label for d1, 2nd element (1) refer to d2, and so on.

How can I group a dataframe according to the labels in a way that:

- d1 and d4 belongs to cluster 0
- d2 and d3 belongs to cluster 1
- d5 belongs to cluster 2

Suppose I have managed to cluster them, how can I calculate the sum of each feature within a cluster such that:

- for cluster 0 (which contains d1 and d4)

  ```
         c1   c2   c3   c4   c5
  d1      5    2    5    6    7
  d4      1    2    3    7    0
  total   6    4    8    13   7
  ```
- for cluster 1 (which contains d2 and d3)

  ```
         c1   c2   c3   c4   c5
  d2      5    6    7    8    2
  d3      4    3    1    9    2
  total   9    9    9    17   4
  ```
- for cluster 2 (which contains d5)

  ```
         c1   c2   c3   c4   c5
  d5      0    3    3    4    5
  total   0    3    3    4    5
  ```

Comment: You say the cluster numbers are randomly generated, but you also gave a mapping of cluster number to d1..d5. I don't see how it could be both. Are you re-grouping the rows, regardless of the row labels? If so, @Happy001's answer is what you want.

Comment: My mistake, I mean the labels are randomly generated, number of clusters are fix. Anyway, I have a hint of how to begin. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [47]: df = pd.DataFrame([[5,    2,    5,    6,    7],
   ....:                    [5,    6,    7,    8,    2],
   ....:                    [4,    3,    1,    9,    2],
   ....:                    [1,    2,    3,    7,    0],
   ....:                    [0,    3,   3,    4,    5]],
   ....:                    columns=['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5'],
   ....:                    index=['d1','d2','d3','d4','d5'])


In [48]: labels = [0,1,1,0,2]

In [49]: for i, cluster in df.groupby(labels):
   ....:         tot = cluster.sum()
   ....:         tot.name = 'Total'
   ....:         print "Cluster %s" % i
   ....:         print cluster.append(tot)
   ....:
Cluster 0
       c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
d1      5   2   5   6   7
d4      1   2   3   7   0
Total   6   4   8  13   7
Cluster 1
       c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
d2      5   6   7   8   2
d3      4   3   1   9   2
Total   9   9   8  17   4
Cluster 2
       c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
d5      0   3   3   4   5
Total   0   3   3   4   5
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Happy001 mentioned, you can use `groupby` directly on your randomly assigned cluster numbers.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[5,    2,    5,    6,    7],
                   [5,    6,    7,    8,    2],
                   [4,    3,    1,    9,    2],
                   [1,    2,    3,    7,    0],
                   [0,    3,   3,    4,    5]], 
                   columns=['c1','c2','c3','c4','c5'],
                   index=['d1','d2','d3','d4','d5'])

from random import randint, seed
seed(1)
labels = [randint(0,2) for i in range(len(df))]

for i, cluster in df.groupby(labels):
  print(cluster.sum())
```

Comment: How can I cluster the d when the labels are a list of randomly generated number in the range(0,2)? Thanks in advance

Comment: @YewJie I edited the answer to accomodate randomly assigned labels.

Answer (score 0):

```
clusters = {'c0': ['d1', 'd4'], 'c1': ['d2', 'd3'], 'c2': ['d5']}
rev_clusters = {v: k for k, d_list in clusters.iteritems() for v in d_list}
df['cluster'] = df.reset_index()['index'].map(rev_clusters).tolist()
for cluster, group in df.groupby('cluster'):
    group.ix['Total'] = group.sum()
    del group['cluster']
    print 'Group {0}\n'.format(cluster), group, '\n'

Group c0
       c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
d1      5   2   5   6   7
d4      1   2   3   7   0
Total   6   4   8  13   7 

Group c1
       c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
d2      5   6   7   8   2
d3      4   3   1   9   2
Total   9   9   8  17   4 

Group c2
       c1  c2  c3  c4  c5
d5      0   3   3   4   5
Total   0   3   3   4   5
```

Comment: How can I cluster the d when the labels are a list of randomly generated number in the range(0,2)? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can just `groupby` a list of length `len(df)`